# How to control MacBook volume from an iPhone?

Tags: macos, ios, remote-control, sound-volume

Is there a way to control the volume of a MacBook using an iOS device?

Ideally I would like to rely on the built-in functionality present in macOS and iOS, but if that's not an option, then I would like to know which workarounds exist.

I am aware that it is possible to enable Screen Sharing in macOS (*System Preferences > Sharing > Screen Sharing*), and then use a VNC client on iOS in order to access the Mac's screen and scroll the volume slider, but this is not very convenient.

Another option I've discovered is to enable the SSH server on macOS (*System Preferences > Sharing > Remote Login*), connect from iOS with an SSH client and run something like `osascript -e "set Volume 10"`.

These options are unnecessarily clunky and I am assuming there might be some built-in option to do this but I couldn't find it so far.

<sup>(Ideally, I would also like to have the possibility to play/pause video and audio playback but since that's player-dependent I'm not expecting much in this sense).</sup>

Comment: I want to extend the amazing macOS app BetterTouchTool if you don’t use it already. Then the iOS extension app to use bonjour protocols to connect through a network.

Comment: I recommend it. I’m not affiliated with the development but both are free with paid features. but the macOS trial is 45 days, you can export and find your work arounds. Give it a whirl! If you ever get an Apple Magic Mouse, BTT gestures with it will change your life.

Comment: I mean... $6.50 isn't bad if it does what you want.

Comment: Indeed, with the companion BTT iOS app I could get it to control the volume. Thank you guys! I've used the app before but didn't know it had an iOS client — very versatile app.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for bringing up BTT Remote! I completely forgot that I had installed the companion app BTT Remote on my iPhone. IMMEDIATELY worked and was the solution I needed.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how you used BTT to solve the problem described in the question?

Comment: There’s a companion app for BTT called BTT Remote. Once you install it on your iPhone or iPad (I think there’s  one for iPads), follow the on-screen instructions and you’re good to go.

Comment: BTT Remote ROCKS. Strongly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called [Remote Control For Mac - Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/remote-control-for-mac-lite/id629019487?mt=8). There is a free version that allows volume control.

I am not affiliated with the software.

Comment: Installing a closed-source server is the least appropriate option for me. I would rather use something like kodi + [ios kodi remote](https://kodi.wiki/view/Official_Kodi_Remote/iOS) which are both open-source and work with both ios and android clients. My question is whether Apple has something OOTB for this use case

Comment: Remote Control for Mac - Lite seems to be abandonware as of 2022-12-21. (Just judging by the last status/version update on the App store.)

Comment: I ended up buying this from following your link. It does sooo much more than just volume. Thanks for the share!